# How to create tri-state checkbox (true / false / null) in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have developed a web application with ASP.NET MVC 4 and Kendo UI. It has a grid which contains a checkbox column. I need to have a tri-state checkbox (true, false, null) in that checkbox column.

If the user ticks the box then its value should be `true`, if the user untick the box then the value should be `false`. Important thing is if user left without ticking the box or unticking it then its value should be `null`.

Is it possible to have three state checkbox in a kendo grid? If yes how to do that?

Comment: How would you that checkbox look like? I mean, from the UI point of view, which is the difference between false and null? Once it has been ticked once, it is not clear to me how it returns to null.

Comment: @OnaBai "false" should display nothing inside the box while "null" should display fully filled box.as well as "true" should display right mark inside the box.i think u got what i mean..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with [this](http://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/) article, the only way of setting a checkbox to `indeterminate` state is by doing it programatically. the problem is that each time that you update the value, the cell containing the checkbox is redrawn and as consequence the third state removed.

You can check this by doing:

```
var grid = $("#stocks_tbl").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: [
        { id: 1, active: true, symbol: "AAPL" },
        { id: 2, active: false, symbol: "AMZN" },
        { id: 3, active: false, symbol: "GOOG" }
    ],
    editable  : true,
    columns   : [
        { field: "symbol", title: "Tick" },
        {
            field   : "active",
            template: '<input class="active" type="checkbox" #= active ? checked="checked" : "" # />'
        }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");

$(document).on("change", ".active", function (ev) {
    $(ev.currentTarget).prop("indeterminate", true);
    $(ev.currentTarget).prop("checked", true);
    alert("Shall I continue?");
    var item = grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
    item.set("active", true);
});
```

If you click on the checkbox, you will see the third state until you close the dialog and we set the value to the checkbox. If we don't set it, the value is not reflected in the model.

Comment: i checked your code and its working as the way you mentioned above.. but the problem is how to get the selected state and save it in the data source?

Comment: Right, as I said the problem is the refresh that disables as from using checkbox since the third state is not valid in HTML. The only idea that comes to my mind is using some _fake_ checkbox

Comment: by the way i found a solution to select the tri-state of checkbox but how to apply this in kendo grid.. im stucked with this.. 

here is the link for solution http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/mGg85/2/

Comment: That's the easy part :-) That what my first part of the code does. The problem is when you update the model that it redraws the checkbox and the you loose the indeterminate

Comment: but i need to know that how to get the selected status of checkbox(like true, false or indeterminate) and pass to the datasource with a button click.. can you please tell me that how to get the status like that..