# Kendo Checkbox is not passing notmapped value to controller

Tags: checkbox, kendo-ui

I am having a problem with the kendo checkbox.  It is not setting the value i check on it and sending to the controller.  It is showing in the javascript model (in a custom save event) that the field is null.  It also hits the model in the controller as null.

How i declare the field:

```
[NotMapped]
    public bool? ValueBool { get; set; }
```

the control is in a partial view and is called like this:

```
@Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(m=> m.ValueBool).Checked(Convert.ToBoolean(Model?.Value ?? "false"))
```

This shows the control with the correct value.

However it's not passing the value when i click "save".  Any ideas?

Comment: Is the ValueBool value getting posted to the controller (and just not binding) if you look at the network tab in dev tools? If you manually click the checkbox to toggle the checkbox does it post then? If so, you'll need to trigger the change event on it.

Comment: manually clicking it does nothing.  It's loaded set to true and unclicking it has no effect.  It still passes null.  The network tab shows "null" for that field.

Answer (score 0):

ValueBool is nullable, so, if you are going for a 'tri-state' checkbox, meaning if the user doesn't touch the field, it stays null, but if they check it, it's true, uncheck it, it's false, you'll need to look at something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17822452/493557

However, since you're converting the nullable bool to an either True or False value, perhaps you aren't looking for that tri-state option and you can either change your ValueBool to not be nullable, or do something like the following:

In your model add a boolean property that returns a non-nullable representation of your underlying nullable boolean:

```
public bool ValueBoolNotNullable //Obviously rename this :)
{
    get
    {
        return ValueBool.HasValue ? ValueBool.Value : false;
    }
    set
    {
        ValueBoolNotNullable = value
    }
}
```

And update your view CheckBoxFor to use that new property:

```
@Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(m=> m.ValueBoolNotNullable)
```

Comment: what we are doing is we have a page of "custom data" that stores the data type in one field and a string representation of the value in the "value" field.  I am attempting to convert this to kendo.

Comment: also it took me a while but i see why you might have thought i was doing a tri-state.  We actually have a custom editor template with a tri-state toggle for those.  I never was able to get kendo to want to save the changed value.  I ended up replacing this control with a dropdown list with a True and False text option.  I did this so i could put a change event on it easily in kendo without reams of javascript.  When the dropdown changes it simply copies the value into the value control's data and triggers it so the model notices.